# how to get to instance local data of jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a plugin that each object has a separate plug-in instance. I made ​​it, but when I want to access the data, I have access to the latest example. However, the function of internal plugins are working properly but that the function call out of plugin will only have access to the latest object.

this example:

```
(function($){
$.fn.MyPlug = function(){
    var $this = this;
    var id = $this.prop('id');

    //fire when click on div object
    $this.on('click', function(){
        alert(id);  // this return correct id
    });

    //fire from out of location
    $.fn.GetId = function(){
        alert(id);
    }
}

})(jQuery)


$('#obj-1').MyPlug();
$('#obj-2').MyPlug();
$('#obj-3').MyPlug();

$('#obj-1').GetId(); //i want return obj-1 but return obj-3! 
$('#obj-2').GetId(); //i want return obj-2 but return obj-3!
$('#obj-3').GetId(); //i want return obj-3 but return obj-3!
```

this link : http://jsfiddle.net/G7hFB/25/
in this example to alert own by click over objects and another by call directly.

Now a question:
How can I have outside access to data such as click method ?

Comment: Simple answer, you can't unless you assign it as a property of the plugin !

Comment: Hint: the object `$.fn` can have only **one** property called "GetId".  Your code is reassigning it on each call to "MyPlugin", so only the last one matters.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/G7hFB/26/

Comment: if this code is reassigning it on each call, why $this.on('click'... don't reassigning and do working correctly ???